# Woocommerce price after discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am not expert on WooCommerce, i cant find how to display price that calculate on it discount from coupon.

This code, display price after coupon, but also with shipping price - what i dont want, i want to display price after discount, before shipping and tax:

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
```

This code display the finnal price without discount and without shipping:

```
$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

So i tried something like that to get price after discount:

```
<?php
 $totalp = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
 $totaldisc = $woocommerce->cart->get_total_discount();
 $resultp = $totalp - $totaldisc; 

 echo ($resultp);
?>
```

But it show "0" number.

So, i guess there is simple function for what i want (i want to get total cart price after discount, before shipping), but i cant find this function.

Comment: What do $totalp and $totaldisc contain?

Comment: @ChenAsraf The copoun discount price. example: i set coupon that give 30 discount of cart, it display the 30 number. Toda :)

Comment: I guess it give "0" because it contains the currency symbol, dont know how to calculate without it. but as i asked, i guess there is function to get total price after discount before shipping

Comment: I see. I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: i was need to use int's or floats without symbols, and the best way was to check WooCommerce docs here:
[Woo - Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_calculate_totals)  , and to search for this variable and use it without ()  (not function). now it work :)

```
<?php

$first_number = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->discount_total;
$sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;

print ($sum_total);

?>
```

Comment: please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality

Comment: Notice that following changes in 2.2 and 2.3 `discount_total` is deprecated.
Have a look at `$woocommerce->cart->get_totals()`
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the currency in the prices, you'll need to remove them.

I couldn't find WooCommerce code to just get the subtotal & discount without currency symbol, so let's just remove them manually:

```
function remove_currency($price) {
    return (double) preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]+/', '', $price);
}

$totalp = remove_currency($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal());
$totaldisc = remove_currency($woocommerce->cart->get_total_discount());
$resultp = $totalp - $totaldisc; 

echo $resultp;
```

Comment: Please echo the price and discount, from what I tested the number is fine.

Comment: if i echo the price and discount seperatly it work, it show the price (lets say one product on cart in price of 180 NIS, and discount 30 NIS) but with the calculation, it suppose to display 150, but it show this weird number.

Comment: i see... so i guess this WooCommerce issue with this calculation method.

Comment: now i got that "get_order_discount_total()" will give the number without currency symbol. i triyng to apply it

Comment: please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old but I would like to inform anyone viewing that Woocommerce 3.x now uses:

```
WC()->cart
```

or you can use just

```
$cart
```

as long as you have the `name_of_my_function( $cart ){}` parameter callable.

Everything above is fine... I'm sure yet in hopes someone is not aware that `$woocommerce` global is no long in use.

There is also a way to loop foreach through the cart items (objects) to pick your price sub-totals using the cart_object.

```
foreach( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key=>$value ) 
{
    $priced    = $value['subtotal'];
    $new_price = $priced - ($predefined_referral_discount * 1);

    $value['data']->set_price( $new_price );    
}
```

Remember: `name_of_my_function( $cart_obj ){}` for this one.
Happy Coding